# Bind click handler to all elements except those of a certain HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a page setup that lets you expend text boxes upon click:

http://hashtag.ly/#NASCAR

It adds an 'active' class to elements upon click and removes it if you click another text box. Now I'd like remove the class if you click on the red background. I'll also want to add elements to the page shortly so it's important that this removal only comes from clicking the red portion which is the `<body>` element.

So here's what I have on the page now: (note the log will be replaced by the removal of the class)

```
$('*:not(li)').click(function(){
    console.log('foo')
});
```

The problem is it logs 'foo' everywhere you click, even directly on the text boxes which are `li` elements. How can I make this work only upon click of the background?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `alert()` for testing. People without Chrome and Opera will be mad when they get a hundred boxes one by one...

Comment: I'll change it to console.log

Comment: @Blender, if people try to execute `console.log()` under Windows Internet Explorer, they would get script errors, are you aware of it?

Comment: I'm just testing here, and I don't think there are that many IE stack overflow users who also have the ability to solve this problem and don't know how to change that console.log in the browser to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're bubbling down the HTML stack.  By putting the handler on *everything*, even if you click on an LI, the event will bubble up to its UL.  Similarly, $('body') will cause bubbling issues.

You're best off creating a div outside of your main stack to handle this.  Imagine an absolutely positioned div behind most of the page.

If you really want to have *everything* fire except for LI, your code would need to look more like this:

```
$('*:not(li)').click(function(){
// do something.
});
$('li').click(function(evt){
// do something else.
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I think I'll go with what is described in the second paragraph.